# Have to make a multiplication table with nested while loops. \t spacing messed up in triple digits

Tags: java

Prints a 15 by 15 table of multiplication values. It outputs fine until 10 x 11. Then the spacing is messed up because of the triple digit values but im not sure how to fix it. Once you run it you can see the issue im having. Can anybody help?

```
public class Lab7bMultiplicationTable
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int first = 1;
      int x = first;

      while (x <= 15)
      {
         int y = first; 

         while (y <= 15) 
         {

         System.out.print(x*y + "\t\t");
         y+=1;
         }

    System.out.println();
    x+=1; 
    }


   }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @shmosel can you try and run it? Towards the bottom right corner the numbers start to make a pyramid shape instead of the uniform rectangle

Comment: I did and it looks fine.

Comment: It's working fine for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

It would only be ok for 2-digit number and wrong for 3-digit numbers if your output device uses a tab width of 3, which is quite uncommon. Standard tab width for output is 8, which is why we cannot reproduce your issue.

To make numbers always print ok, don't use tabs. Instead use `printf` to specify a number width of your choosing, e.g. to handle 3-digit numbers use `"%-3d "`, where the `-` makes the number left-aligned.

Also, your `while` loops can be simple `for` loops, which are easier to read, since all the loop logic is on the same line.

```
int first = 1;
for (int x = first; x <= 15; x += 1) {
    for (int y = first; y <= 15; y += 1) {
        System.out.printf("%-3d ", x * y);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Output*

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26  28  30  
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36  39  42  45  
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48  52  56  60  
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  
6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72  78  84  90  
7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84  91  98  105 
8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96  104 112 120 
9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  99  108 117 126 135 
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100 110 120 130 140 150 
11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99  110 121 132 143 154 165 
12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96  108 120 132 144 156 168 180 
13  26  39  52  65  78  91  104 117 130 143 156 169 182 195 
14  28  42  56  70  84  98  112 126 140 154 168 182 196 210 
15  30  45  60  75  90  105 120 135 150 165 180 195 210 225
```

A table like that does however look better when the numbers are right-aligned, so remove the `-` character from the format string.

```
int first = 1;
for (int x = first; x <= 15; x += 1) {
    for (int y = first; y <= 15; y += 1) {
        System.out.printf("%3d ", x * y);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Output*

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15 
  2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24  26  28  30 
  3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36  39  42  45 
  4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48  52  56  60 
  5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75 
  6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72  78  84  90 
  7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84  91  98 105 
  8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96 104 112 120 
  9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  99 108 117 126 135 
 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 130 140 150 
 11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99 110 121 132 143 154 165 
 12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96 108 120 132 144 156 168 180 
 13  26  39  52  65  78  91 104 117 130 143 156 169 182 195 
 14  28  42  56  70  84  98 112 126 140 154 168 182 196 210 
 15  30  45  60  75  90 105 120 135 150 165 180 195 210 225
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that the instructions were to use while loops and escape sequences for the spacing and my teacher managed to do it so there must be a way that I just cant see. Is there a way to change the tab width? I use jgrasp if that affects anything.

Comment: @C.Domingos Try running your code in a command prompt. It should have a tab width of 8. Otherwise see if there is a setting for the tab width in the command prompt window.